# Including DB2JCC4 in Tomcat 7

Tags: db2, tomcat7

I have just upgraded to Tomcat v7.  I am trying to include a jar in the lib that my java classes need.  It is DB2JCC4.JAR. I use this to access DB2 on an IBM mainframe.
This used to work fine in Tomcat6.

When I include the jar, then I get errors such as:

---

```
    Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7\webapps\dbs
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
    .....

    caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: null is 
    not a Java .class file....
```

---

I have tried putting URIEncoding in the Server.XML but that does not help.

When I take out the DB2JCC4 jar file, I do not get startup errors.  Of course, then I cannot access DB2!  I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 14):

Try changing `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties` and add `DB2JCC4.jar` to `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip` property value. It is used to turn off classpath scanning (which is used across JavaEE 6 specs implementations).

Comment: yes! this is the thing to do! I had the same problem, and this answer helped my in solving it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the exception no longer occurs :) I was hoping there would be a way of "fixing" the JAR file itself, but this is also good ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you were wondering why the issue is happening in the first place and not just a workaround you can find the answer [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LI72814). IBM has acknowledged the issue and has provided options for fixing it. Essentially a few of the class files are corrupt.